# Need to replace an unknown amount of Spaces in URL with Dashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, spaces

Need to check for a series of spaces and convert those to dashes in htaccess.
There are a handful of different bad urls that I'm redirecting and currently they work fine if the tag is one word... if there's a space it 404's with /word1%20word2 when it should be /word1-word2.

Now...that said - there's not always just one space... sometimes there's 2 but could be up to 6 as far as I'm seeing in G.webmaster tools conflicts.

My current rewrite that works for the url sequences below.

```
RewriteRule ^.+\(offset\)/+.*?/\(tag\)/([^.]+)$ /tag/$1 [R=301,L]
```

works for: www.domain.com/index.php/Blog/(offset)/48/(tag)/word1

works for: www.domain.com/Blog/(offset)/328/(tag)/word1

works for: www.domain.com/Tags/(offset)/24/(tag)/word1

does not work for: www.domain.com/index.php/Blog/(offset)/48/(tag)/word1%20word2%20word3

does not work for: www.domain.com/Blog/(offset)/328/(tag)/word1%20word2

does not work for: www.domain.com/Tags/(offset)/24/(tag)/word1%20word2

SOO... I'm beside myself trying to figure out how to capture an unknown set of spaces and replace them with dashes. Halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... it seems that the code here works. [301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

I have that rule AFTER my original one and it seems to be working just fine. Hope this helps anybody figure out the issue too. :)

Comment: That regex won't quite work as coded.  You'll need to use `(?:\s|%20)` instead of the couple remaining instances of `[^\s%20]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if it is possible to match an unknown number of whitespaces and replace then just using mod_rewrite.

So one solution would be to redirect internally (without the `R`) to a simple PHP, pass the whitespace-separated value as a parameter to the PHP script, do the necessary replacements in PHP code and then let PHP send an external redirect to the corrected URL (by setting the header Location: /new-url), a similar approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467784/htaccess-rewriting-unlimited-subdirectories/6472966).

If you are looking for a pure .htaccess / mod_rewrite solution anyway, then this is something that you might start with:

```
RewriteRule ^temprewrite/([\S]+)$ /tag/$1  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^temprewrite/(.*?)\s(.*) /temprewrite/$1-$2
RewriteRule ^.+\(offset\)/\d+/\(tag\)/(.*) /temprewrite/$1
```

- The third line does the preprocessing by extracting the whitespace-separated tag. It gets rewritten internally and will match either the first or the second rule.
- The first rule does the final redirect if no more whitespaces as matched by `[\S]+` are found.
- The second rule splits the temporary value into two parts separated by the first whitespace `\s`, concatinates the parts with a `-` and passes the result back to the rewrite engine, where either the first or the second rule will match again.

Please note that this "code" is not fully tested and might miss some rare cases and/or lead to multiple internal rewrites, but I think it "works well enough" to give it a try.

Comment: I couldn't answer myself for 8 hours because of some shitty stackoverflow rule... but here's what I found and did to make it work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces
I have that rule AFTER my original one and it seems to be working just fine. Hope this helps anybody figure out the issue too. :)